# Where can I see my full list of Questions and Answers in my profile page of Stack Exchange Android App?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, android-app

I want to see all my Questions and Answers in a particular SE site - [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) - profile page through Stack Exchange Android App. How can I see that? When I tried to see that I found only Top Posts(5) and Top Tags.

Comment: Currently, it's impossible. You might consider to change this to [tag:feature-request] instead (search first in case it's a dupe feature request).

Comment: I no longer think this is duplicate, since the other one is much broader, and have literally 0% to be ever done.

Comment: Read this short question (you will be able to see your questions but not answers, I tested it in my android and it showed my 4 questions but not my answers): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271428/viewing-all-my-questions-from-the-app

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, for *questions*, just type `user:me` in the search field (unlike the search box on the website and the iOS app, it's automatically limited to questions only), and voila:

[image]