# Viewing all my questions from Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I know there is a way to view all my questions in reverse chronological order from the PC by going to my profile. But I would like to do the same from the mobile app for Android. On Android in the left upper hand corner I can only see the latest answers to my posts, but I would be able to view all my posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to view all your questions by going to the stack you want and searching for `user:me`. But due to some bug, this search doesn't yield answers (it's a bug because on the desktop sites it works properly showing all the posts), so as for answers, you can only view top of them by going to your profile (left menu > first item) and clicking the appropriate site.

[image]

Comment: Hopfully that bug will be fixed sometimes soon.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of where the 'user:me' would be in the Android SEapp?

Comment: @Jack Sure, updated.

Comment: Thanks @nicael  Very useful picture.

Comment: Yes, I tested your answer and in the app it shows the questions (all of them, happily) but not the answers, on the pc shows both Q & A.

Comment: It's a nice feature, just a bit hidden