# User's top tags in the profile lead to a search query with no results in the Android app

Tags: bug, search, android-app, api

If I open my profile for a specific site in the SE Android app, then click on one of the top tags, I get taken to a search query with few or no results. To reproduce:

- Click on your avatar at the top left to open the profile page,
- Then click on one of the specific site entries (in my case Stack Overflow),
- Then click on one of the top tags, here:

  > [image: screnshot]

You get taken to a search query like: "user:4428462 [jsoup]" (that's my user id), but which only returns results for questions I've asked in that tag, not answers too:

> [image: screenshot 2]

I think this should be fixed, so that clicking on one of the Top Tags in the profile on the Android app returns useful results.

Worth noting that clicking on the top tags in the profile on desktop does work correctly, and shows both my questions and answers in that tag (but the search query used is exactly the same, huh?), as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the bug as you're describing it: the problem is, the answers are excluded from the search for some unknown reason (probably a bug too, [have noticed it once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271429)), and it's not possible to search for the answers at all. So if you had some questions asked in this tag, they would appear in the results.

Comment: That does make sense - indeed, I only get results if I've asked a question in that tag. I hope they fix it..