# Posts by a user to a specific site

Tags: support, android-app

I am trying to search all posts by a user to a specific site excluding other sites from my mobile phone.

How do I find all posts by a specific user `@JoeDoe` to a specific site e.g. SuperUser using the Android SE app?

Comment: On the iOS app, you can click on the user profile and hit `All Posts`.

Comment: @Patrick no such thing in the android app, only the top 5 posts (questions and answers together, by score) - it was always inferior to the iOS app. Anyway, only way from the app is by opening a post in browser, then you can see it all in the profile page. (There is already a feature request [asking to add the full list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262284/where-can-i-see-my-full-list-of-questions-and-answers-in-my-profile-page-of-stac) to the android app profile)